# IIS Dot (Period) in Url

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, url-routing

Is it possible in IIS 7.5 to allow urls with period (not as extension)? I am working on setting user profile urls to be something like site.com/firstname.lastname but I get "No matching constructor was found" error. I wonder if this is possible in IIS and if so how? 
This is asp.net web forms application and I am trying to intercept HttpRequestBegin process to determine what user it is and then redirect to actual user profile page (site.com/user/profiles/userid).

Comment: What version of ASP.NET are you using? You might be able to use a custom route with a constraint.

Comment: .net 4.0 its a web forms based app.